# How do I see the network adapter statistics in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, statistics

I remember there was bytes/packets sent/received since connection established in the past but I cannot find it in the adapter properties now.

BTW, when I hover over the `network connection` icon in the tray, it displays `Network: Internet access, Unindentified network, No network access`, yet, you see I have posted this question anyway.

[image]

[David figured the screen](https://superuser.com/a/934019/392687) I was looking. The problem was that status was not available in my case (for some bug in my Windows session).

[image]

Comment: So the real question should be: Why is *status*  greyed out?

Comment: @nixda I have created the question to ask how to open up the status dialog. I was asking for the path to that dialog. It is answered now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How do I see the network adapter statistics in Windows 7 / 8 / 10?

1. Start "Control Panel" > "Network Connections"
2. Right click one of your network connections and select "Status"

   [image: Windows 7, Network Connection Status]

This image is from Windows 7, but the dialog is almost identical in Windows 8 and 10.

Comment: And if you want to also see errors in this window set this registry entry to 1: SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network\Connections\StatMon\ShowLanErrors

Comment: For me, displaying errors only works on Windows 7 Enterprise, not on Windows 7 Professional. Can someone confirm this behavior?

Comment: Can't confirm about Windows 7 pro, but just tried on 8.1 pro and it now shows the errors. Also, it's under HKLM in case anyone is looking for the right path.

Answer (score 32):

I think you might be after something like the result of the `netstat -s` command.

It will show you statistics like this:

```
IPv4 Statistics

  Packets Received                   = 125858
  Received Header Errors             = 0
  Received Address Errors            = 130
  Datagrams Forwarded                = 0
  Unknown Protocols Received         = 0
  Received Packets Discarded         = 315
  Received Packets Delivered         = 126500
  Output Requests                    = 83395
  Routing Discards                   = 0
  Discarded Output Packets           = 0
  Output Packet No Route             = 1
  Reassembly Required                = 0
  Reassembly Successful              = 0
  Reassembly Failures                = 0
  Datagrams Successfully Fragmented  = 0
  Datagrams Failing Fragmentation    = 0
  Fragments Created                  = 0

IPv6 Statistics

  Packets Received                   = 7
  Received Header Errors             = 0
  Received Address Errors            = 0
  Datagrams Forwarded                = 0
  Unknown Protocols Received         = 0
  Received Packets Discarded         = 2
  Received Packets Delivered         = 117
  Output Requests                    = 444
  Routing Discards                   = 0
  Discarded Output Packets           = 0
  Output Packet No Route             = 6
  Reassembly Required                = 0
  Reassembly Successful              = 0
  Reassembly Failures                = 0
  Datagrams Successfully Fragmented  = 0
  Datagrams Failing Fragmentation    = 0
  Fragments Created                  = 0

ICMPv4 Statistics

                            Received    Sent
  Messages                  241         2
  Errors                    0           0
  Destination Unreachable   241         2
  Time Exceeded             0           0
  Parameter Problems        0           0
  Source Quenches           0           0
  Redirects                 0           0
  Echo Replies              0           0
  Echos                     0           0
  Timestamps                0           0
  Timestamp Replies         0           0
  Address Masks             0           0
  Address Mask Replies      0           0
  Router Solicitations      0           0
  Router Advertisements     0           0

ICMPv6 Statistics

                            Received    Sent
  Messages                  3           18
  Errors                    0           0
  Destination Unreachable   0           0
  Packet Too Big            0           0
  Time Exceeded             0           0
  Parameter Problems        0           0
  Echos                     0           0
  Echo Replies              0           0
  MLD Queries               0           0
  MLD Reports               0           0
  MLD Dones                 0           0
  Router Solicitations      0           12
  Router Advertisements     0           0
  Neighbor Solicitations    0           3
  Neighbor Advertisements   3           3
  Redirects                 0           0
  Router Renumberings       0           0

TCP Statistics for IPv4

  Active Opens                        = 1232
  Passive Opens                       = 4
  Failed Connection Attempts          = 1647
  Reset Connections                   = 121
  Current Connections                 = 28
  Segments Received                   = 104462
  Segments Sent                       = 66346
  Segments Retransmitted              = 1695

TCP Statistics for IPv6

  Active Opens                        = 0
  Passive Opens                       = 0
  Failed Connection Attempts          = 0
  Reset Connections                   = 0
  Current Connections                 = 0
  Segments Received                   = 0
  Segments Sent                       = 0
  Segments Retransmitted              = 0

UDP Statistics for IPv4

  Datagrams Received    = 26472
  No Ports              = 297
  Receive Errors        = 18
  Datagrams Sent        = 15279

UDP Statistics for IPv6

  Datagrams Received    = 2
  No Ports              = 0
  Receive Errors        = 2
  Datagrams Sent        = 338
```

Or if you want Layer 2 statistics, you can use `netstat -e` to get only those related to Ethernet:

```
Interface Statistics

                           Received            Sent

Bytes                     604513390        48753903
Unicast packets              566790          389160
Non-unicast packets           81665            5275
Discards                          0               0
Errors                            0               0
Unknown protocols                 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This question shows up in search results for dropped *ethernet* frames, so I'll add the only way I've found to get *ethernet* layer 2 stats (not layer 3+) on Windows (tested on 10, but might work on 7).

In Powershell:

```
Get-NetAdapterStatistics | Format-List -Property "*"
```

Normally the dropped/error/retransmit stats are hidden, so piping into Format-List shows all stats.

Source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netadapter/get-netadapterstatistics?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple once you know it and essentially the same way as in older versions:

- Open the Network and Sharing Center (name might actually be different; not using English locale).
- On the top left side bar there is an option to open the adapter settings. This leads you to the classic network listing.
- Now double-click any adapter to get the classic property window with the adapter stats.

Answer (score 0):

Besides:

- Overall stats: `netstat.exe -e`
- List stats per protocol: `netstat.exe -s`
- List stats per interface: `powershell Get-NetAdapterStatistics`

you can reset stats to zero with `netcfg -d`, unfortunately it is very intrusive (deletes interfaces so you have to reboot to continue the work).